# What defines a landing gear bogie?

Tags: terminology, landing-gear

[image]
([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Undercarriage_Layouts_Center_01.jpg)) A Boeing 737 main landing gear arrangement.

---

What defines a landing gear bogie (truck)?

In its [airframe maintenance handbook](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/amt_airframe_handbook/media/ama_Ch13.pdf), the FAA defines it as:

> When more than two wheels are attached to a landing gear strut, the attaching mechanism is known as a bogie.

But, they go on and describe the Boeing 777 main landing gear (MLG) as:

> A triple bogie main landing gear assembly.

That means each **lateral** pair of wheels is a bogie, which is what the [undercarriage arrangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undercarriage_arrangements) Wikipedia article calls a 2-wheel nose landing gear.

For me, a bogie is when a strut holds a **longitudinal** arrangement of wheels (like [trains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogie)). For example, the MLG of a Sukhoi Su-34 (shown below) would be a bogie, but not a Boeing 737 MLG, despite both having two-wheels each.

Are there technical terms to distinguish the two images shown in this post?

[image]
([Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%A1%D1%83-34_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%A2%D0%A3_08.jpg))

Comment: I believe “triple bogie” should be read as “bogie that is a triple” (i.e. has three axles) rather than as “three bogies”.

Comment: A triple bogie is three over par. :P

Comment: @TomMcW +3 for you.

Comment: [This](http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2009/US/05/15/new.york.tire.plane/art.wheel.three.wgrz.jpg) is known as a birdie. Good thing it wasn't an eagle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term bogie [initially meant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bogie) (atleast in Britain) an assembly of wheels forming a pivoted support at either end of a railway coach, which provided flexibility on curves.

So, the term bogie refers to the set of wheels, rotating about the (landing gear) axis, while their arrangement- lateral or longitudinal doesn't matter.

An old patent for [Bogie undercarriages for aircraft](https://www.google.com/patents/US3091416) notes:

> ... a bogie having multiple wheel assemblies mounted on transverse rotational axes spaced one behind the other ...

The issue is that the term has been in use for a long time an has come to mean a number of things (even in railways, the entire carriage can be called a bogie)- so while the correct term is to call it a four (or six) wheel bogie rather than double or triple bogie, it is used quite often. Also, as I already noted, whether it is lateral or longitudinal doesn't matter as long as they are attached to the same (nose or main) gear.

Comment: @ymb when I said already noted, I was referring to my statement in second para, not that in the patent.

Comment: `as shown below` Is there supposed to be an image?

Comment: @TomMcW I think "shown below" refers to the quoted text.

Comment: @TomMcW I've edited it slightly. Hope it makes better sense now.